# How can I use JavaScript to find Project Completion Date by adding number of days (Project Duration) to Current Day in mm/dd/yyyy format?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a quote form for web design prospects and new to JavaScript and been having a hard time with the JavaScript to determine the Project Completion Date based on the sum of the Project Duration (in # of days) + Project Start Date (Set to Today's Date by default in `mm/dd/yyyy` format).

Would definitely appreciate an experienced helper to get solve this beginner's problem very much.

```js
function SetDate() {
            var date = new Date();
            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
            if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

            var today = month + "-" + day + "-" +year;


            document.getElementById('Date').value = today;
            document.getElementById('Project_Start_Date').value = today;
        }
```

```html
<td>Projected Duration Estimate**:</td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Projected Duration" id="Projected_Duration"><label> Days</label></td>
<td>Project Start Date:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Project Start Date" id="Project_Start_Date"></td>
<td>Project Completion Date:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Project Completion Date" id="Project_Completion_Date"></td>
```

Comment: you could do this vanilla JS but have you checked out moment.js https://momentjs.com/  you could do this in 1 line by including the library.  Might be worth looking into if you are going to do more date and time validation on this project

Answer (score 0):

use moment.js's add for this, `moment().add(7, 'days')`

// it gives you date after 7 days from current date)

refer link https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Answer (score 0):

`moment` is just great when working with dates.

```js
function render() {
  
   const estimate = parseInt(document.getElementById("Projected_Duration").value);
   const startDateStr = document.getElementById("Project_Start_Date").value;
   if(startDateStr) {
       const startDate = moment(startDateStr);
       let endDate = startDate.add(estimate, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
       document.getElementById("Project_Completion_Date").value = endDate;
   }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<td>Projected Duration Estimate**:</td> 
<td><input type="number" min="0" name="Projected Duration" id="Projected_Duration" onchange="render()"><label> Days</label></td>
<td>Project Start Date:</td>
<td><input type="date" name="Project Start Date" id="Project_Start_Date" onchange="render()"></td>
<td>Project Completion Date:</td>
<td><input type="date" name="Project Completion Date" id="Project_Completion_Date" readonly></td>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me to compute Project Completion Date via JavaScript by adding Project Duration & Start Date. Thank you bravemaster for taking the time to help me solve this problem I was running to and had spent a total of about 2-3 hours researching and trying different methods.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and approve my answer if it was helpful.